# Looking for memcached or redis alternative on Windows

Tags: database, redis

I have trouble finding a suitable alternative to a key-value database like `memcached` and `redis` on Windows. Can anyone recommend a solution that is production ready and safe?

`redis` was never fully ported to Windows due to the lack of the missing `fork(3)` functionality and since redis dumps states to disk.

Same for memcached. Afaik, there were some projects focusing or even finishing a port, but there is a bigger story involved why it's not that easy to find a proper memcached version for Windows either.

Thanks!